# Illustrator CS6 pattern brush stroke alignment

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

I am trying to create pattern brush in AI CS6, my line and corner elements are precisely aligned, but when I make swatches and subsequently a pattern brush, elements are misaligned, I check the swatch dimensions etc. Cannot find the cause. Anyone knows what is happening?

Left - corner element, right, main (line) element

[image: Left - corner element, right, main (line) element]

alignment is correct

[image: alignment is correct]

pattern brush applied to a rectangle, corner and line elements are not aligned

[image: pattern brush applied to a rectangle, corner and line elements are not aligned]

closeup

[image: closeup]

[Project File](https://filebin.net/0qg4kf7njj9yszo9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not you. Brush corner alignment can defy logic at times and it *often* takes trial and error to get the corners to align correctly. This is somewhat more true before Adobe implemented their "auto corners" options (CS6 or earlier).

I have my `Nudge` settings at 0p0.125. So, it's a very minute nudge:

[image]

I selected the line artwork for the corner (just the art not the defining rectangle) and nudged it down twice....

[image]

It is out of alignment in the actual artwork, intentionally. This is done to compensate for the how the corner is aligning on the path.

Then select the art and defining rectangle and reset it as the corner piece...

[image]

It aligns correctly.

Then looked at the vertical edge of the brush corner...

[image]

Nudge the artwork right twice as well and reset it as the corner....

[image]

So after nudging down twice and right twice, the corner is aligned in the brush.

[image]

This is commonly what I've had to do for brush corner pieces... create the artwork, apply it as a corner.. test, adjust, test, adjust, test, until it aligns correctly. I nudged it down once, reapplied it, still off, nudged a second time, reapplied it and that aligned.

Comment: Thanks! will do as I you advised. I expected more from Adobe, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, in CS6 and earlier especially, the corner art has never aligned to the base path *exactly* the same as the section art. Sometimes it's because the corner piece is not defined as the same size as the straight piece, i.e. the corner is twice/half the height of the straight piece. But if both pieces are defined as *exactly* the same size, you'd expect them to align exactly the same way, but they often don't.